# Adding a maximum limit to the number of post using python

Tags: python, django

I need to limit the number of posts in Django queries. I have tried to add a min and max but nothing seemed to have worked. I have added home.html into the code.

Example: I should only have the 15 most recent posts in my blog. The rest can be seen by clicking on the category button.

Home.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}




<h1>Posts</h1>

<ul>
{% for post in object_list %}

    <li><a href="{% url 'article-detail' post.pk %}">{{post.title}}</a> 
<style>
    a {
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }
</style>
        - <a href="{% url 'category' post.category %}">{{ post.category }}</a> - <a href="{% url 'show_profile_page' post.author.profile.id %}">{{ post.author.first_name }} 
    {{ post.author.last_name }}</a> - {{ post.post_date }} <small>

        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            {% if user.id == post.author.id %}

            - <a href="{% url 'update_post' post.pk %}">(Edit)</a>

            <a href="{% url 'delete_post' post.pk %}">(Delete)</a>
            {% elif user.id == 1 %}

            - <a href="{% url 'update_post' post.pk %}">(Edit)</a>

            <a href="{% url 'delete_post' post.pk %}">(Delete)</a>

            {% endif %}

        {% endif %}


    </small><br/>
    {{ post.snippet }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>


{% endblock %}
```

`view.py:`

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'
    ordering = ['-id']

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
            cat_menu = Category.objects.all()
            context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
            context["cat_menu"] = cat_menu
            return context
```

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    header_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='images/')
    title_tag = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='intro')
    snippet = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='post_likes')
    dislikes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='post_dislikes')
```

Comment: Are you talking about pagination? https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/

Comment: @ToniSredanović No I meant I should only have the 15 most recent posts in my blog. The rest can be seen by clicking on the category button.

Comment: Just add this queryset in your initial template: `Post.objects.filter(<how_you_want_to_filter>).order_by('-<order_based_on_some_date>')[:15]`

Comment: something like this. But wont i need to add this in my views.py also post it as an answer so its easy for future readers to find the answer easily. @bdbd

Comment: Yes you need to add it somewhere in your home view. Maybe in `get_context_data`, something like `recent_posts`?

Comment: Sorry, I dont really understand what code I exactly need to add inside (<how_you_want_to_filter>) and ('-<order_based_on_some_date>') @bdbd

Comment: How do you want to get the post from the request? Is it by user? And how would you determine how a recent a post is? Is there any date on the post?

Comment: HI, There is a specific id for every post created. @bdbd

Comment: Can you share your `Post` with all the fields

Comment: I just added it @bdbd.

Comment: can you show your template `home.html`? this will probably help figure out why things aren't working even after bdbd's answer

Comment: Yep done it @Abhyudai, Sorry did not see your comment It was hidden.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have another template for displaying categorised objects when you click category button. As you said

> "I should only have the 15 most recent posts in my blog. The rest can
> be seen by clicking on the category button."

In this case you can use a simple hack to display most recent posts from your table.
query all objects in descending order in `views`

```
    all_objs = Post.objects.all().order_by('-id')
```

Then use   `{% if forloop.counter <= 15 %}`   to display last 15 items only. as follow.

templates

```
{% for post in object_list %}

   {% if forloop.counter <= 15 %}

       <h4>{{obj}} #or anything really that is meant to be shown on the home page.</h4>

   {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I will definitely try and tell you the results in 10 mins thankyou.

Comment: Also I have suggested an edit please peer review it.

Comment: yeah. I tried to keep it as simple as I can. I did not understand  `ordering = ('-id')`  this line just before the query. what is this for.

Comment: Ok cool. I couldn't understand what you meant in your question. Can you explain it?. Did you meant `from django import template` this importing or anything else

Comment: I will just post the link here to the question.... If its okay with you.

Comment: It is Ok, let me check it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68481791/using-fancy-html-templates?noredirect=1#comment121028399_68481791

Comment: Hi, I just remembered 'ordering' itself is a function in python and you do not need to define it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
    context["cat_menu"] = Category.objects.all()
    context["most_recent_posts"] = Post.objects.filter(author=self.request.user).order_by('-post_date')[:15]
    return context
```

This will get the 15 most recent posts authored by the current user, ordered by the date it was posted.

Then just handle displaying this in `home.html` for example:

```
<ul>
{% for p in most_recent_posts %}
    <li>{{ p.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: am sorry, I missed a tiny bi in my views.py. I think you might need to tweak your code a bit. check my edited post.

Comment: Yeah just add this to your current one.

Comment: sorry, That di d not work. I am not sure why. I added your def func with some tweaks but no it did not work sadly.

Comment: Updated to work with your current implementation. Note that you also need to modify `home.html` to actually use this new context.

Comment: A small question do I just leave the ordering = [-id] function as it is or do I have to change it as well.

Comment: No need as that context data will have its own ordering

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235049/discussion-between-kaushik-and-bdbd).

Comment: What did not work exactly? Added an example for you.

Comment: Yes, I did that but I got this error though  "Reverse for 'article-detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:"

Comment: Do you think thats related to this?

Comment: Hey Lets move that conversations  to the chat above plz and I still have that error.

Answer (score 1):

Just limit your query to the latest 15 entries sorted by `post_date`:

```
cat_menu = Category.objects.latest("post_date")[:15]
```

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/pagination/

The best way is Django Pagintion.

```
{% for contact in page_obj %}
    {# Each "contact" is a Contact model object. #}
    {{ contact.full_name|upper }}<br>
    ...
{% endfor %}

<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.shortcuts import render

from myapp.models import Contact

def listing(request):
    contact_list = Contact.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(contact_list, 25) # Show 25 contacts per page.

    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    return render(request, 'list.html', {'page_obj': page_obj})
```

Comment: This is also helpful I might even use this later.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Django pagination api . Manage your data through page number. Initially pass 1 and after that page number given by pagination.

```
 paginator = Paginator(yourquerysetdata, 20)
        page_num = request.data.get('page')
        result = yourSerializerName(paginator.get_page(page_num) many=True).data
        try:
            page = paginator.page(page_num)
        except:
            page = paginator.page(1)

        count = paginator.num_pages

        resultobj = paginator.get_page(page_num)
        has_prev = resultobj.has_previous()
        has_next = resultobj.has_next()
        page_range = resultobj.paginator.page_range.stop - 1
        if has_prev:
            prev_page_no = resultobj.previous_page_number()
        else:
            prev_page_no = 0

        if has_next:
            next_page_no = resultobj.next_page_number()
        else:
            next_page_no = None

        context = dict()
        context['page'] = page.number
        context['page_no'] = count
```

Comment: Hi, I love your idea but I don't want separate pages but rather just limiting the amount of posts in 1 page.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. You just have to modify the query that you are using to fetch the posts. 
In the `get_context_data()` method, replace `cat_menu = Category.objects.all()`
  with `cat_menu = Category.objects.all().order_by('-post_date')[:15]`. This will limit the number of results to 15 most recent objects.
For more understanding, you can take a look at the official Django docs for [Limiting QuerySets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets).