# Using fancy Html templates

Tags: javascript, python, html, templates

After I added a lots of thing to my blog I wanted to add a template but to do that it seemed like I need to override. So I created a new app that is exact replica of the first one. in the new one I would add the template and then copy and paste a bunch of code into the new one. But When I did that I was caught in an error. which was really hard to fix. After I imported the template I added a static bar/code to everything that has images, js, videos and others. But still there was no change. I hope someone can help me. If anything else is needed please do ask. I am really sorry for pasting the entire code. If I edit the code I might miss something important. There is a million difference between how it should look and not. but I cant seem to work it out.

Here's how mine should looks:

```
https://www.free-css.com/assets/files/free-css-templates/preview/page252/scenic/
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(request,'home.html',{})
```

Code:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<title>Scenic HTML Template</title>


<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'myblog/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'myblog/css/font-awesome.min.css/' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'myblog/css/magnific-popup.css' %}">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'myblog/css/owl.theme.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'myblog/css/owl.carousel.css' %}">

<!-- MAIN CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'myblog/css/tooplate-style.css' %}">

</head>
<body>

<!-- PRE LOADER -->
<div class="preloader">
     <div class="spinner">
          <span class="sk-inner-circle"></span>
     </div>
</div>


<!-- MENU -->
<div class="navbar custom-navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
     <div class="container">

          <!-- NAVBAR HEADER -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
               <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
               <!-- lOGO -->
               <a href="home.html" class="navbar-brand">Scenic</a>
          </div>

          <!-- MENU LINKS -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#home" class="smoothScroll">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">Studio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#team" class="smoothScroll">Our People</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll">Let's talk</a></li>
               </ul>
          </div>

     </div>
</div>


<!-- HOME -->
<section id="home" class="parallax-section">
     <div class="overlay"></div>
     <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

               <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="home-text">
                         <h1>Your Website has a video background!</h1>
                         <p>Feel free to download and use HTML templates from Tooplate</p>
                         <ul class="section-btn">
                              <a href="#about" class="smoothScroll"><span data-hover="Discover More">Discover More</span></a>
                         </ul>
                    </div>
               </div>

          </div>
     </div>

     <!-- Video -->
     <video controls autoplay loop muted>
          <source src="{% static 'myblog/videos/video.mp4' %}" type="video/mp4">
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
     </video>
</section>


<!-- ABOUT -->
<section id="about" class="parallax-section">
     <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

               <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="about-info">
                         <h3>Introducing Scenic</h3>
                         <h1>This template is designed for you. Sed ornare, tortor nec placerat lacinia, leo quam rutrum leo, eget posuere ipsum sem eu justo. Integer nunc libero.</h1>
                    </div>
               </div>

          </div>
     </div>
</section>


<!-- PROJECT -->
<section id="project" class="parallax-section">
     <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

               <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <!-- PROJECT ITEM -->
                    <div class="project-item">
                         <a href="{% static 'myblog/images/project-image1.jpg' %}" class="image-popup">
                              <img src="{% static 'myblog/images/project-image1.jpg' %}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                         
                              <div class="project-overlay">
                                   <div class="project-info">
                                        <h1>Beautiful Women</h1>
                                        <h3>Click to pop up!</h3>
                                   </div>
                              </div>
                         </a>
                    </div>
               </div>

               <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <!-- PROJECT ITEM -->
                    <div class="project-item">
                         <a href="{% static 'myblog/images/project-image2.jpg' %}" class="image-popup">
                              <img src="{% static 'myblog/images/project-image2.jpg' %}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                         
                              <div class="project-overlay">
                                   <div class="project-info">
                                        <h1>Nulla efficitur quam</h1>
                                        <h3>Sed ligula accumsan</h3>
                                   </div>
                              </div>
                         </a>
                    </div>
               </div>

               <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <!-- PROJECT ITEM -->
                    <div class="project-item">
                         <a href="{% static 'myblog/images/project-image3.jpg' %}" class="image-popup">
                              <img src="{% static 'myblog/images/project-image3.jpg' %}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                         
                              <div class="project-overlay">
                                   <div class="project-info">
                                        <h1>Large Sea Wave</h1>
                                        <h3>Nam feugiat dui in nisi</h3>
                                   </div>
                              </div>
                         </a>
                    </div>
               </div>

               <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <!-- PROJECT ITEM -->
                    <div class="project-item">
                         <a href="{% static 'myblog/images/project-image4.jpg' %}" class="image-popup">
                              <img src="{% static 'myblog/images/project-image4.jpg' %}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                         
                              <div class="project-overlay">
                                   <div class="project-info">
                                        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
                                        <h3>Mollis aliquam faucibus urna</h3>
                                   </div>
                              </div>
                         </a>
                    </div>
               </div>               

          </div>
     </div>
</section>


<!-- TEAM -->
<section id="team" class="parallax-section">
     <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

               <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-sm-12">
                    <!-- SECTION TITLE -->
                    <div class="section-title">
                         <h1>Meet Our People</h1>
                    </div>
               </div>

               <div class="clearfix"></div>

               <div id="owl-team" class="owl-carousel">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 item">
                         <div class="team-item">
                              <img src="{% static 'myblog/images/team-image1.jpg' %}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                              <div class="team-overlay">
                                   <ul class="social-icon">
                                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a></li>
                                   </ul>
                              </div>
                         </div>
                         <p>Catherine Jann</p>
                         <h3>Head Designer</h3>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 item">
                         <div class="team-item">
                              <img src="{% static 'myblog/images/team-image2.jpg' %}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                              <div class="team-overlay">
                                   <ul class="social-icon">
                                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-github"></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
                                   </ul>
                              </div>
                         </div>
                         <p>Luke Wara</p>
                         <h3>Speciality Focus</h3>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 item">
                         <div class="team-item">
                              <img src="{% static 'myblog/images/team-image3.jpg' %}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                              <div class="team-overlay">
                                   <ul class="social-icon">
                                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-dribbble"></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-behance"></a></li>
                                   </ul>
                              </div>
                         </div>
                         <p>Mono Mana</p>
                         <h3>Art director</h3>
                    </div>

                    
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 item">
                         <div class="team-item">
                              <img src="{% static 'myblog/images/team-image1.jpg' %}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                              <div class="team-overlay">
                                   <ul class="social-icon">
                                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a></li>
                                   </ul>
                              </div>
                         </div>
                         <p>Cherry Lynn</p>
                         <h3>Marketing Manager</h3>
                    </div>
               </div>

          </div>
     </div>
</section>





<!-- FOOTER -->
<footer>
     <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

               <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6">
                    <h2>Digital Studio</h2>
                    <p>321 Donec et justo id risus, Malesuada pharetra,<br> Tristique vestibulum,<br> Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                    
                    
               </div>

               

               <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                    
                    <h2>About Us</h2>
                    <p>Sed vestibulum posuere ante, eget blandit metus. Morbi sodales feugiat erat, et placerat sapien suscipit ut.</p>
                    <ul class="social-icon">
                         <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
                         <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
                         <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
                         <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    
               </div>

               <div class="clearfix"></div>

               <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="copyright-text">
                         <p>Copyright © 2018 Company Name 
                         
                         | Design: Tooplate</p>
                    </div>
               </div>
               
          </div>
     </div>
</footer>

<!-- SCRIPTS -->
<script src="{% static 'myblog/js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'myblog/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'myblog/js/jquery.parallax.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'myblog/js/owl.carousel.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'myblog/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'myblog/js/magnific-popup-options.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'myblog/js/modernizr.custom.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'myblog/js/smoothscroll.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'myblog/js/custom.js' %}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myblog',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UNSE.png [1]:

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/olYzg.png [1]:

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5vFL.png [1]:

Comment: "..I was caught in an error" What error? Can you post error you are getting?

Comment: Its not exactly an error but rather not working. I meant the css and js are not responding and there are no images and videos. I can add a image if you want.

Comment: @Nemanja I have added pictures that explain a bit more. I hope so.

Comment: So what happens when you open the page source and then click on the style sheet links? Do they work? There is a typo in "myblogcss/font-awesome.min.css" too.

Comment: No, they do not work. Only the ones with fake urls work and none of the images and photos work. I will share the template link with you in the post check in within 2 mins.

Comment: could you show your settings,py and your views.py also.

Comment: Yes I have done it. @Rasheedkotoor

Comment: Do you have the static folder which contains all static fiels. Did you push this project to git?

Comment: Yes I created a static folder inside that there is myblog folder and inside that I pasted all the code like, images, vids, CSS, font awesome and js

Comment: Can you also add your project directory/file structure in the post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, i'm not exactly sure where did you put your template "home.html" file so i made the assumption of you putting it in the 'static' file same with all the other assets (js/css folders)

So i basically made the template section in settings.py the following:

```
    TEMPLATES = [
        {'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')],},]
    BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
       os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    ]
```

then inside "home.html", i changed every single 'myblog' to '.'
and it worked just fine.

Oh, since the Auto-generated template settings basically has a specific way of searching, provided at "https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES"

So provided your current settings of static files

```
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    ]
```

Your django settings tells it to look for static on the same folder that manage.py is located at, (The value of the BASE_DIR)
So in your html, remove 'myblog/'
so the engine looks for 'static/js, static/css'
however if you want to keep "myblog", inside static file which must be in the same folder as manage.py, create 'myblog' and move all the folders (js, css..) inside it
so your file path would look like

```
mainsite: app_name
          another_app
          manage.py
          static:
                 myblog:
                        css
                        js
```

Apologies for the terrible answer format.

Comment: Hi, But I already have a templates file in my setting which  was autogenerated. Also I got an error. Please provide ow you have edited.

Comment: I have adjusted the question to your data, added more explanations. my apologies

Comment: Yep You have done it. Thanks it works a lot better now.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your settings.py :- replace `BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent` on the top of the file just after importing os.

try this in setttings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myblog',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

Comment: did you push your code in git hub or anywhere else. I would like to have a look on the entire code

Comment: No, entire code already was there. What other code are you asking. Sorry for the late reply BTW.

Comment: let me see your views.py and the folders and files in static folder.

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'myblogcss/font-awesome.min.css/' %}">` in your 2nd stylesheet link, you are missing a '/' `myblog/css` and you have an extra '/' at the end.

Comment: Also there are a lot of files I am not sure it will fit there are some with hundreds of lines.

Comment: you should check if the path of static files mentioned in html is correct.

Comment: It is correct from what I know. I made the path or home.html correctly. I checked if it worked before I added the code